# css expression :not with two condition

Tags: html, css

I have this weird situation that I cannot make work :not that has two condition. Basically
I want to hide all div in a container except those having specific class.

For example this is the html

```
<div id="container">

  <div class="show"></div>
  <div class="extra"></div>
  <div class="about"></div>

  <div class="sample1"></div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div class="sampleetc"></div> 
</div>
```

Now my css expression is like this , but it is not working

```
 #container > div:not(.show), #container > div:not(.about){
     display:none;
   }
```

Any ideas why it is not working or good css expression for this, i presume, :not does not work with two condition, or i am guessing the first expression already hide `.about`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can just chain the `:not` selector like this:

```css
div#container > div:not(.show):not(.about)
{
    display: none;
}
```

It appears to work correctly on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ce7pr/).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want. Hide all inside the container but div.show and the next one

```
   #container > div:not(.show) + div{
     display:none;
   }
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/bCFgu/)